# Realm is rewriting instead of updating nested array of objects

Tags: swift, realm

For example, i have two classes:

```
class Message : Object {

    dynamic var text_ : String = ""

    convenience init(text: String) {

        self.init()
        text_ = text
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "text_"
    }

}

class UserProfile : Object {

    dynamic var username_ : String = ""

    var messages = List<Message>()

    convenience init(username: String) {
        self.init()
        username_ = username
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "username_"
    }

}
```

So i've got the user, and the list of all his messages and i want to have ability to update that list when i got new UserProfile instance from somewhere:

```
let realm = try! Realm()

let user1 = UserProfile(username: "user1")
let message1 = Message(text: "message1")
user1.messages.append(message1)

try! realm.write {

    realm.add(user1, update: true)
}
let results1 = realm.objects(UserProfile)

print("Before updating: \(results1[0].messages)")

let theSameUser = UserProfile(username: "user1")
let message2 = Message(text: "message2")
theSameUser.messages.append(message2)

try! realm.write {

    realm.add(theSameUser, update: true)
}
let results2 = realm.objects(UserProfile)

print("After updating: \(results2[0].messages)")
```

The output is :

```
Before updating: List<Message> (
    [0] Message {
        text_ = message1;
    }
)
After updating: List<Message> (
    [0] Message {
        text_ = message2;
    }
)
```

But it should contain both 2 messages, in "After update", because there is only one user exists. What should i do with that?

**UPDATE:**
There are Realm example in documentation. The only difference with my example, is the list of Realm Objects:

```
// Creating a book with the same primary key as a previously saved book 
let cheeseBook = Book() 
cheeseBook.title = "Cheese recipes" 
cheeseBook.price = 9000 
cheeseBook.id = 1 

// Updating book with id = 1 
try! realm.write { 
realm.add(cheeseBook, update: true) 
} 
If a Book object with a primary key value of ‘1’ already existed in the database, then that object would simply be updated. If it did not exist, then a completely new Book object would be created and added to the database."
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem here seems to be that Realm doesn't know that theSameUser is actually the same user as the first user before this block of code gets executed since you are adding the user to the Realm here:

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(theSameUser, update: true)
}
```

The result of that is when you say

```
theSameUser.messages.append(message2)
```

`theSameUser.messages` is actually empty. So if you want to append a message to "user1" you should fetch it from Realm and then append the new message.

Comment: This. The new user is not associated with any Realm when you expect it to be equal to the old user. Therefore they aren't equal yet.

Comment: I've used primaryKey to avoid that situation, and docs says: "If your model class includes a primary key, you can have Realm intelligently update or add objects based off of their primary key values using Realm().add(_:update:)."

Comment: Yes but the property `messages` has been updated to `[message2]`

Comment: I think i got it. Thank you! But are there any elegant solution to this problem? Not to fetch, append and write in 3 steps

Comment: @Andreas is on point here. When you append message2 to the list of messages list of messages is empty so after append it only contains message2 and when you update the user, [message2] replaces the previous list of messages which is [message1.]

Comment: Without accessing the existing user you can't update its messages as far as I know, so your best bet is to get the user from Realm and then just append the new message in a write block.

Comment: But what is the point of "Add or update" function then? If i need to find by myself that object, and if it exists then update different fields, and if not - then create a new objects. And how i should find him, calculating the primaryKey by myself and passing it through the filter func? I think that Realm should do all this stuff fo me, otherwise there is no point in "update"

Comment: @bcamur If i have 20 properties in UserProfile class, which user can change, i should update them by hands, including appending new messages?

Comment: It is pretty straightforward for your use case actually. Just do something like this and you should be allright: let user = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(UserProfile.self, key: "user1") try! realm.write {
    user.messages.append(message2) //change anything you want about this UserProfile here and it will be changed in the database.
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106735/discussion-between-alexey-kuznetsov-and-bcamur).